# What is the swift equivalent of this cast?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to convert this into swift, or at least find something that does the same thing.

```
 size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
 size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

 GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));
```

I need to initialize the spriteData pointer in swift of the right size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two of those are of type `size_t`, which maps to `Uint` in Swift, and the last is `GLubyte`, which maps to `UInt8`. This code will initialize `spriteData` as an array of `GLubyte`, which you could pass to any C function that needs an `UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>` or `UnsafePointer<GLubyte>`:

```
let width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage)
let height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage)    
var spriteData: [GLubyte] = Array(count: Int(width * height * 4), repeatedValue: 0)
```

What do you need to do with `spriteData`?

Comment: I am passing spriteData to CGBitmapContextCreate(&spriteData,...) to load in a bitmap, that I can load into OpenGL. I have been struggling with it for hours. There are literally no swift examples of loading a texture into OpenGL on the internet that I can find. Even Apple does't have an examples that I know if.

Comment: Any success? If you've gotten it working, post a question about the trouble you were having and then add your solution as an answer!

Comment: I have had absolutely no success

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is:

```
var spriteData = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.alloc(Int(width * height * 4))
```

Note that, if you did this, you have to `dealloc` it manually.

```
spriteData.dealloc(Int(width * height * 4))

/// Deallocate `num` objects.
///
/// :param: num number of objects to deallocate.  Should match exactly
/// the value that was passed to `alloc()` (partial deallocations are not
/// possible).
```

Comment: What parameter am I supposed to add for dealloc()? It is asking for an int.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the answer. I think you should accept the @NateCook answer. If you use `Array`, Swift handles the memory.